# What use do we have from "MSBuild project build log file verbosity" setting in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, build

I want to build with the textual diagnostics verbosity in VS. I also create binary log, but I need the text diagnostics for the very first line which explains why VS hands off the project to msbuild in the first place.

The options dialog makes me wonder - is it possible to redirect this output to a file up-front? The second verbosity option "MSBuild project build log file verbosity" implies it, but I do not see any option to provide the file name.

Any ideas?

[image: tting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a C# project "MSBuild project build log file verbosity" is useless.
It's relevant in C++ projects.

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-save-and-configure-build-log-files?view=vs-2019